# How can I separate button operation in javascript and Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I made sign up form page using Django. When I fill in the register form, data is included in database. But, when I click the email check button, register button also is clicked and the page is reloaded. How can I separate these two button?

```js
$('.email-check-btn').click(function (){
    const email = $('#email').val()
    if (email === ''){
        alert('please check the form')
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'email-check?email=' + email,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (response){
            if (response.result !== 'success') {
                alert(response.data)
                return
            }
            if (response.data === 'exist') {
                alert('that email is already exist!')
                $('#email').val('').focus()
            } else {
                alert('good, you can use it!!')
            }
        }
    })
})
```

```py
def email_check(request):
    try:
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=request.GET['email'])
    except Exception as e:
        user = None

    result = {
        'result': 'success',
        'data': 'not exist' if user is None else 'exist'
    }
    return JsonResponse(result)
```

```py
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = request.user.is_authenticated
        if user:
            return redirect('/main')
        else:
            return render(request, 'sign_in_and_up.html')

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        user_id = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2', '')
        nickname = request.POST.get('nickname', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')

        if password != password2:
            return render(request, 'sign_in_and_up.html', {'error': 'check your password'})
        else:
            if user_id == '' or password == '' or nickname == '' or email == '':
                return render(request, 'sign_in_and_up.html', {'error': 'fill in all the blank'})

            exist_user = get_user_model().objects.filter(username=user_id)
            if exist_user:
                return render(request, 'sign_in_and_up.html', {'error': 'already exist'})
            else:
                UserModel.objects.create_user(username=user_id, password=password, nickname=nickname, email=email)
                return render(request, 'sign_in_and_up.html')
```

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Vg8.png)

Comment: You're getting error because you don't have trailing / in url

Comment: Also the submit issue is probably in HTML, not Django. For checking email use `<button type="button">...`. We can't see template so I can't be sure.

Comment: I really appreciate! In HTML, the button type was 'submit', so I changed to 'button' and it works properly. Thank you again!